# error when trying to link libraries

Tags: linux, libraries, cc

I am trying to compile my c code on linux i386.
I have the sqlite3 library at:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

but the linker does not find them. I even specified the path manually with the -L option which I suspect is not necessary:

```
cc -pthread -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L../i386/debug/lib/ ./bin/i386/debug/*.o  -lsculib -lpthread -lsqlite3 -o ../i386/debug/bin/myProgram
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../i386/debug/bin/core] Error 1
```

any ideas why it does not find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you also need the header files.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed the problem. Although, I'm now getting some strange errors: undefined reference to `sqlite3_free' but it is defined in /usr/include/sqlite3.h Below is how I'm using it.   ----------------- database.h
#ifndef __DATABASE_H__
#define __DATABASE_H__

#include <sqlite3.h>
----------------- database.c
#include "database.h"
sqlite3_free(errMsg);   <---- Causes link Error

Comment: I figured out. In my link command, I should specify the sqlite3 package after the source filename which requires it.